# How to implement Open Flash Chart 2 on Symfony

Tags: symfony1, open-flash-chart, openflashchart2, ofc

I'm trying to use **Open Flash Chart 2** on my symfony project by including the ofc2 library on one of my controller's action.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. When i call the action **it prints nothing** :'(

There is a plugin for this, but it uses an outdated version of OFC.

Anyone have had any success showing Open Flash Chart 2 on their site?

Here's how my controller's actions file looks:

```
<?php

class chartActions extends sfActions{

    public function executeTestChartData(sfWebRequest $request){
        $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Type','text/plain');

        include('/cidat/lib/php-ofc-library/open-flash-chart.php');

        $title = new title( date("D M d Y") );

        $bar = new bar();
        $bar->set_values( array(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1) );

        $chart = new open_flash_chart();
        $chart->set_title( $title );
        $chart->add_element( $bar );

        $output = $chart->toPrettyString();

        return $this->renderText($output);
    }
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance,

Vic

Comment: Any more info to go on apart from "it doesn't work"? PS, welcome to SO :-)

Comment: Thanks, richsage, I just updated my post

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally solved it. Here's what I did:

1. Copied `open-flash-chart.php` to `/lib/php-ofc-library`
2. Copied the rest of the files included in the OFC2 php lib to `/apps/my-app/lib` directory
3. Last, removed `include('/lib/php-ofc-library/open-flash-chart.php');` from my controller's action.

That's it. Don't forget to clear cache.

Cheers

Comment: If a PHP class has dependencies and they're not `include()`'ed properly in the class definitions, it's not your fault :)
Glad you solved it.